# Cannot move out of borrowed content when trying to transfer ownership

Tags: reference, rust, move-semantics, borrow-checker

I'm writing a linked list to wrap my head around Rust lifetimes, ownership and references. I have the following code:

```
pub struct LinkedList {
    head: Option<Box<LinkedListNode>>,
}

pub struct LinkedListNode {
    next: Option<Box<LinkedListNode>>,
}

impl LinkedList {
    pub fn new() -> LinkedList {
        LinkedList { head: None }
    }

    pub fn prepend_value(&mut self) {
        let mut new_node = LinkedListNode { next: None };

        match self.head {
            Some(ref head) => new_node.next = Some(*head),
            None => new_node.next = None,
        };

        self.head = Some(Box::new(new_node));
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

But I am getting the following compilation error:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of borrowed content
  --> src/main.rs:18:52
   |
18 |             Some(ref head) => new_node.next = Some(*head),
   |                                                    ^^^^^ cannot move out of borrowed content
```

Newer versions of Rust have a slightly different error:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `*head` which is behind a shared reference
  --> src/main.rs:18:52
   |
18 |             Some(ref head) => new_node.next = Some(*head),
   |                                                    ^^^^^ move occurs because `*head` has type `std::boxed::Box<LinkedListNode>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

I'm thinking that the `head` node must currently be owned by `self`, which is the linked list. When I assign it to `new_node.next`, there is probably a change of ownership that will happen.

I would rather not clone the value if possible as that seems wasteful. I don't want to just "borrow" it for the duration of the function. I really want to transfer its ownership.

How do I do that?

I have already looked at [cannot move out of borrowed content when unwrapping a member variable in a &mut self method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28194335/error-cannot-move-out-of-borrowed-content-on-mut-self) and [Cannot move out of borrowed content / cannot move out of behind a shared reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28158738/cannot-move-out-of-borrowed-content).

I tried removing the match arm as suggested in the accepted answer in one of those questions and defining `next` in the creation of the new `LinkedListNode`, but I get the same error message.

I have successfully added an `append` method which takes a `LinkedListNode` to add to the end of the list.

Comment: possible duplicate of [\`cannot move out of dereference of \`&mut\`-pointer\` while building a sorted linked list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27750985/cannot-move-out-of-dereference-of-mut-pointer-while-building-a-sorted-linke)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

> Cannot move out of borrowed content when trying to transfer ownership

At a high-level, this is against-the-grain for Rust. You cannot transfer ownership of something borrowed *because you don't own it*. You shouldn't borrow my car  (`&Car`) and then give it to the first person you see on the street! This is still true even if I lend you my car and allow you to make changes to it (`&mut Car`).

You cannot move `head` out of a `&self` at all because you cannot mutate the value.

You cannot move `head` out of a `&mut self` because this would leave the `LinkedList` struct in an inconsistent state - one of the fields would have an undefined value. This is a core measure of Rust's safety guarantees.

In general, you will need to follow something from [How can I swap in a new value for a field in a mutable reference to a structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27098694/155423) to replace the existing value.

In this case, you can use [`Option::take`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.take). This will leave the variable where it is, changing it in-place to a `None` and returning the previous value. You can then use that value to build the new head of the list:

```
pub fn prepend_value(&mut self) {
    let head = self.head.take();
    self.head = Some(Box::new(LinkedListNode { next: head }));
}
```

A more generic solution is to take ownership of the struct instead of borrowing it. This allows you to do whatever you want to it. Note that we take `self` by-value, not by-reference:

```
pub fn prepend_value(mut self) -> LinkedList {
    self.head = Some(Box::new(LinkedListNode { next: self.head }));
    self
}
```

Comment: Which of the two solutions would you say is more idiomatic code?

Comment: Since you have a `Node` and a wrapper `List`, I'd probably use the version with `take`; I think people understand `&mut self` more than `self`. If the list was just composed of the `Node`s, you'd have to use the `self` version. I'd probably annotate it as `#[must_use]` as well, to help guide users.

Comment: @Shepmaster Thank you soooo much, I had no idea `take` was used like this.