# Is there a way to tell the compiler that I am managing ownership of a variable in a loop?

Tags: loops, rust, ownership

I'm trying to give ownership of a variable to a function in a loop and I have my own boolean to ensure it happens only one time, however the compiler tells me the value was moved in the previous iteration.

Here is an example:

```
fn take_ownership(a: String) {
    println!("{}", a);
}

fn main() {
    let mut a = true;
    let hello = "Hello".to_string();

    for _ in 0..5 {
        if a {
            a = false;
            take_ownership(hello);
        }
    }
}
```

With this code, the compiler tells me:

```
error[E0382]: use of moved value: `hello`
  --> src/main.rs:12:28
   |
12 |             take_ownership(hello);
   |                            ^^^^^ value moved here in previous iteration of loop
```

Is there a way to tell the compiler "it's ok, I will handle it"? I don't want to use references (`&`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The usual way of telling the compiler "It's OK, I will handle it" is to use `unsafe`. You *could* use `unsafe` here along with some deep `ptr` magic, but that would be extremely brittle and difficult to prove correct.

However, this is a safe and easy thing to do with an `Option`:

```
let mut a = Some("Hello".to_string());

for _ in 0..5 {
    if let Some(hello) = a.take() {
        take_ownership(hello);
    }
}
```

In the original, there's no type-level relationship between `a` and `hello`, so the compiler can't be sure that `hello` is only moved once. `Option` encodes the invariant "there *might* be a thing here, or it might be gone" into the type, so the compiler can know that `take_ownership` is only called when there is something to pass to it.

[`.take()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.take) is a method that replaces `a` with `None`, returning the contents (if any). Because this method does not consume the `Option`, it's fine to call it multiple times in a loop. [Cannot move out of borrowed content when trying to transfer ownership](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28258548/cannot-move-out-of-borrowed-content-when-trying-to-transfer-ownership/28268208#28268208) is a related question.