# How can I apply an arbitrary in-place operation to a &mut reference?

Tags: rust, in-place, mutable-reference

Is there a way to write this function without requiring `AddAssign` or `Clone` on `T`?

```rust
use std::ops::Add;

fn increment<T: Add<isize, Output = T>>(x: &mut T) {
    *x = *x + 1;
}
```

As written, I get the error:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `*x` which is behind a mutable reference
 --> src/lib.rs:4:10
  |
4 |     *x = *x + 1;
  |          ^^ move occurs because `*x` has type `T`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

Comment: *without requiring* — What changes *are* we allowed to make?

Comment: With the currently written function signature, this can only be solved via the solutions in [Temporarily move out of borrowed content](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29570781/155423); TL;DR "no, you can't do this without unsafe code".

Comment: Since `add` takes ownership of the arguments, `x` would be left in an undefined state _if `add` panics_. That would introduce memory unsafety, and safe Rust does not permit that. See also [Cannot move out of borrowed content when trying to transfer ownership](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28258548/155423)

Comment: There are plenty of other answers that involve changing the function signature / trait bounds, like adding `Copy` (but you've already ruled out `Clone` for unspecified reasons) or being able to add using a reference as the argument. It's not very fun for answerers to spend their time attempting to guess what _other_ limitations you will impose after they've spent their time providing an answer.

Comment: @Shepmaster Your third comment makes it clear why this is impossible. I didn't consider the problem with recovering from panics. The comment I added and deleted was because I didn't realize you were the same person making three comments. I was trying to answer them one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Shepmaster's response in the comments, I gather that this is impossible without changing the function signature because the function being applied may panic leaving `x` in a memory-unsafe state if the panic is recovered from.

However by adding the `Default` constraint it becomes possible using `mem::replace`.

```
use std::mem;
use std::ops::Add;

fn increment<T: Default + Add<isize, Output = T>>(x: &mut T) {
    let y = mem::replace(x, Default::default());
    *x = y + 1;
}
```

Now if `add` panics, `x` will have the default `T`.

Comment: Not impossible, just not accepted in safe Rust. That's why crates like `replace_with` / `take_mut` exist. If you are going to use `Default`, you might as well do `*x = mem::take(x) + 1;` You could also change the bound to `for <'a> &'a mut T: Add<isize, Output = T>` and do `*x = &mut *x + 1;`

Comment: Hang on,
Rust has `QuantifiedConstraints` ?
I haven't seen `for` used in that way before. Where's the documentation on that?

Comment: More information is linked in the duplicate [How to write a trait bound for adding two references of a generic type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34630695/155423) as well as [How does for<> syntax differ from a regular lifetime bound?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35592750/155423).